# How to Transform SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics, core-animation

I am trying to transform SKShapeNode with shearing, but CGAffineTransform not works with Sprite Kit. What will you suggest?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe use the init(path: CGPath) constructor for SKShapeNodes, and construct the path by applying the CGAffineTransform. For example, if you have an initial path, I think CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath will make a copy with the transform applied that you could then make the shape node with.

Comment: @bg2b, you can update an SKShapeNode path on the fly with node.path.  Provide an answer using `node.path = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(node.path,transform)` and I will give you an upvote

Comment: I solved this with SKTransformNode, i've created my SKShapeNode and added it to transform as child.
Transform node has options, xRotation & yRotation for doing some rotations in 3D

Comment: SKTransformNode is the right solution for this.